# How to display tool window from VSIX extension?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2022

I need to display some tool window from my VSIX code, and in old versions of the Visual Studio I used this code and it worked fine:

```
EnvDTE.Window toolwindow = _dte.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindxxxx);
```

But now, in the new 2022 version of the studio when I just opened fresh studio instance and my tool window is hidden my `toolwindow`  is always null, until I open my tool window by myself only after it I can get window object.

Is there any DTE command or something to display some tool window from code, same as I do trough the main menu in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the same signature, but I've had luck wrangling tool windows in VS 2022 using [`AsyncPackage.FindToolWindowAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.asyncpackage.findtoolwindowasync?view=visualstudiosdk-2022).

It provides an option to create the desired tool window if it doesn't already exist, which sounds like it might be helpful for your scenario.